# How to grab text from a messy string in java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am reading a text file which contains movie titles, year, language etc.
I am trying to grab those attributes.

Suppose some string are like this :

```
 String s = "A Fatal Inversion" (1992)"
 String d = "(aka "Verhngnisvolles Erbe" (1992))    (Germany)"
 String f =  "\"#Yaprava\" (2013) "
 String g = "(aka \"Love Heritage\" (2002)) (International: English title)"
```

How can i grab title, year, country if specified, what sort of title if specified from this?

I am not very good at using regex and patterns, but I don't know how to find what sort of attribute it is when they are not specified. I am doing this because I am trying to generate xml from a textfile. I have the dtd for it but im not sure I need it to use it in this case.

Edit: Here is what i have tried.

```
    String pattern;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
    Matcher m;



    Pattern number = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher num;

    m = p.matcher(s);

    num = number.matcher(s);

    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }

    if(num.find()){
        System.out.println(num.group(0));
    }
```

Comment: the data is too much messy and inconsistent. As data will increase so will inconsistency and it will become increasilngly difficult to capture the data

Comment: @AvinashRaj check edit. thanks

Comment: @rock321987 yes i know its messy and inconsistent. but there will always be a way to do it.

Comment: `regex` will work on consistent data or at least data for which pattern exists

Comment: @rock321987 do you have any other suggestions I can do instead?thanks

Comment: This is very non-trivial task, so don't expect that there's easy solution. Even if you find some solution for this, there'll always be a chance of errors.

Please elaborate why you need this program and where you get your data from, because instead of solving direct problem it makes sense to bypass the problem.

Comment: You have to use `machine learning` or some `statistical model` to do this because the attributes can be anywhere

Comment: @Yura This is part of my assignment problem. I need to convert a text document which has about 10k lines to xml by extracting particular fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you extract the year first as this seems fairly consistent. Then I'd extract the country (if present) and the rest I'll assume is the title.

For extracting the countries I'd recommend you hardcode a regex pattern with the names of known countries. It might take some iterating to determine what these are as they seem to be pretty inconsistent.

This code is a bit ugly (but then so is the data!):

```
public class Extraction {
    public final String original;
    public String year = "";
    public String title = "";
    public String country = "";

    private String remaining;

    public Extraction(String s) {
        this.original = s;
        this.remaining = s;
        extractBracketedYear();
        extractBracketedCountry();
        this.title = remaining;
    }

    private void extractBracketedYear() {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(" ?\\(([0-9]+)\\) ?").matcher(remaining);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            this.year = matcher.group(1);
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        remaining = sb.toString();
    }

    private void extractBracketedCountry() {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\((Germany|International: English.*?)\\)").matcher(remaining);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            this.country = matcher.group(1);
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        remaining = sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        for (String s : new String[] {
                "A Fatal Inversion (1992)",
                "(aka \"Verhngnisvolles Erbe\" (1992))    (Germany)",
                "\"#Yaprava\" (2013) ",
                "(aka \"Love Heritage\" (2002)) (International: English title)"}) {

            Extraction extraction = new Extraction(s);
            System.out.println("title   = " + extraction.title);
            System.out.println("country = " + extraction.country);
            System.out.println("year    = " + extraction.year);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Produces:

```
title   = A Fatal Inversion
country = 
year    = 1992

title   = (aka "Verhngnisvolles Erbe")    
country = Germany
year    = 1992

title   = "#Yaprava"
country = 
year    = 2013

title   = (aka "Love Heritage") 
country = International: English title
year    = 2002
```

Once you've got this data, you can manipulate it further (e.g. "International: English title" -> "England").

Comment: Hi, Thanks  for the answer. However is it possible to adjust the regex so i can get the country from a 
        string " aka \"Teatre catal� amb Manel Fuentes\" (2004)) (Spain:          Catalan title) (working title)"

Because at the moment the regex has a word wrap around it so it only matches if its just Spain in brackets. How would i fix this?

Comment: The way Stack Overflow works, you need to ask this as a new question. Try to narrow in on the specific problem and what you've tried etc.